# Best way to get unique list without changing the Order

Tags: java

I have a list of string or list of integers of 20,000 items

Now it contains duplicates...However i don't want to disturb the order of the item.

We can easily convert a list to Set for unique Set unique = new HashSet(list);

However the above breaks the sequential order of the items.

What would be the best approach for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try stream `distinct`

```
yourList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Update1**:
As I know, this is the best solution.

1. `list.contains(element)` will do 2 loop processes. One for iterate the element and add it to new list, one for check element is contained -> 0(n*n)
2. `new LinkedHashSet()` will created a new LinkedHashSet, and a new Arraylist output -> issue about memory. And the performance, i think it is equals with `stream distinct`

**Update2**: we must ensure that the output is a `List`, not a `Set`

1. As I know, `stream distinct` use `HashSet` internally. It is an more efficient memory implementation than `LinkedHashSet` (which is hash table and linked list implementation of the set interface) in our case.
   [Detail here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)
2. If you apply `LinkedHashSet`, the source code will something like below, so we have 1 ArrayList and 1 LinkedHashSet.

   output = new ArrayList(new LinkedHashSet(yourList));
3. I did a small benchmark with 1k for-loop.

```java
int size = 1000000;
Random rand = new Random((int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000));
List<Integer> yourList = new ArrayList<>(size);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    yourList.add(rand.nextInt(10000));
}
// test1: LinkedHashSet --> 35ms
new ArrayList<Integer>(new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(yourList));
// test2: Stream distinct --> 30ms
yourList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Will it cause performance issue. Is it better than going with iteration and checking with if (!list.contains(element)) {

Comment: Absolutely sure, this is a better solution than `list.contains(element)`.

Comment: @hnban can you explain how using stream is better in memory? in-order to identify the unique elements in a list stream should be using a hashcode internally to identify unique elements. if this is the case I don't see any major memory/performance improvement than using a LinkedHashSet(). also I am pretty sure that LinkedHashSet doesn't use a arraylist.

Comment: Yes, `LinkedHashSet` doesn't use an `ArrayList`, it uses `LinkedList` instead. `ArrayList` what I meant is a output of function `output = new ArrayList(new LinkedHashSet(yourList))`

Comment: Your main concern seems to be performance, yet you only guess and did no benchmarks whatsoever. Usually, people are far off when guessing about performance. Might be worth to actually measure the difference, the outcome is maybe completely different.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [java.util.LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) to get unique elements without changing the order:

```
Set<String> uniqueSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(list);
```

One other way is to use `distinct()`:

```
list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())
```

But `distinct()` uses `LinkedHashSet` internally. There is no need for unnecessary procedure.

So best way is using the LinkedHashSet constructor:

> LinkedHashSet(Collection c) Constructs a new linked hash
>   set with the same elements as the specified collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to eliminate duplicates, you can use LinkedHashSet it will maintain the order.

if String

```
Set<String> dedupSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

if Integer

```
Set<Integer> dedupSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

Comment: Will it cause performance issue. Also, does it maintains the order when list is being passed as constructor argument. Is it better than going with iteration and checking with if (!list.contains(element)) {

Comment: yes, It will maintain the order, it's basically a hashtable with doubly linked list. Definitely much better than going through a list. for a linked hashset most cases it should be Big O(1), which is a constant time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to break the order, then Iterate the list and make a new list as below.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>();       
    for (Integer element : list) { 
        if (!newList.contains(element)) {       
            newList.add(element); 
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the bellow code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String list[] = {"9","1","1","9","2","7","2"};
    List<String> unique = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
        int count = unique.size();

        if(count==0) {
            unique.add(list[i]);
        }else {
            boolean available = false;
            for(int j=0; j<count; j++) {
                if(unique.get(j).equals(list[i])) {
                    available = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(!available) {
                unique.add(list[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    //checking latest 'unique' value
    for(int i=0; i<unique.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(unique.get(i));
    }

}
```

It will return `9 1 2 7`, but I haven't tried up to 20,000 collection lists, hopefully there are no performance issues